# Renders centered on PC browser but not align in iphone browser

Tags: iphone, html, css

Well, i have one centered div used as a footer simply by: `<div id="bottom-footer">Powered by Coolname</div>` and the style:

```
#bottom-footer {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 1px;
text-align: center;
}
```

And that renders ok in PC browser:
[image]

But when you tried on an iphone, its looks like this:

[image]

Clearly not centered, what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there is a margin or a padding on the containing `body` element or the div itself. Add this to your style sheet to reset the browsers natural behaviour:

```
html {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#bottom-footer {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 1px;
text-align: center;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width:100%`

```
#bottom-footer {
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 1px;
text-align: center;
}
```